# Darknet: Loss & mAP chart in jupyter-notebook

Tags: python-3.x, yolo, darknet

Is possible plot loss & mAP chart of training results of YOLOv3 with Darknet in jupyter-notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot through matplotlib

```py
assert os.getcwd()=='/content/darknet', 'Directory should be "/content/darknet" instead of "{}"'.format(os.getcwd())

# Plotting training result after 2000 epochs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
train_result = plt.imread("chart.png")
plt.axis(False)
plt.imshow(train_result)
```